# set background in karate test features

Tags: karate

In our test features (for API testing) in Background we create our datas needed for test cases (ex: users, their datas ...). We would like to use the same test features in different modes. How we can set datas in Background? I mean how we can use "different" Backgrounds for our test features. Ex: we would like to run the same test features:

- in admin or non admin mode, so in Background we need to create a user account, then generate an access token, then using this token to add some datas for this user; this token is used for every scenario;
- with injected data we only need to generate an access token which is used for every scenario

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many, many ways, refer the docs on [conditional logic](https://github.com/intuit/karate#conditional-logic).

Also note this trick, you can dynamically `call` features like this because the `read()` function is pure JS:

```
* call read('mysetup-' + karate.env + '.feature')
```